# Setting a base url for sourcemaps in a Web Essentials .bundle file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, web-essentials, source-maps

We're using the nice Web Essentials to create javascript bundles.
We'd like to be able to use the full sources in Chrome Developer Tools, which should work using the generated source maps.

However, in the generated .map file, the location of the listed source files does  not correspond to their url.

Suppose there's just one file in the bundle, to make for an easy example. Then this part of the generated .map file lists the location of the source file:

`"sources":["/Views/js/vendor/angular-1.3.14.js"]`

But this is the base url of our web-app: `https://localhost:44300/Websharing`

Notice the `/Websharing` part

This leads to Chrome trying to download

`https://localhost:44300/Views/js/vendor/angular-1.3.14.js`

when it should download

`https://localhost:44300/Websharing/Views/js/vendor/angular-1.3.14.js`

Is there a way to instruct Web Essentials to use a base url or folder for .map files?